# Do I need to install a bootloader?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, uefi

I'm trying an Arch Linux build on a recently found SSD that I thought I'd lost, and I'm at the part of mounting the drives and installing the bootloader.  Do I need to install `GRUB` or `systemd-boot` if my computer already has a UEFI bootloader?  i.e. wouldn't I just be able to boot in to that and select which drive to boot from there?  Or is it something that my UEFI needs in order to boot that drive?

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using UEFI on that system then you have a UEFI partition there.  You can place the kernel (at `/boot/vmlinz-linux` in arch) and the initramfs (at `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` in arch) directly into the UEFI partition.

Then you can configure the UEFI loader, for example adding `\loader\entries\arch.conf` with `options root=` for the kernel to figure out where is the root filesystem it shall use.

```
title    Arch Linux
linux    \vmlinuz-linux
initrd   \initramfs-linux.img
options  root=PARTUUID=14420948-2cea-4de7-b042-40f67c618660 rw
```

You then need to add the UEFI partition to mount as `/boot` inside `/etc/fstab`.  This is needed for Arch to be able to update the kernel and initramfs through `pacman`.  Example `/etc/fstab` line:

```
<UEFI part> /boot vfat defaults 0 0
```

(Disclaimer: I never used this direct mount into `/etc/fstab`, since UEFI always have a directory called `EFI` this will result in `/boot/efi`.  I believe there is some automation needed to copy the kernel from `/boot` into `/boot/efi` on every kernel update.)

---

Another option may be to create a directory in the UEFI partition, say `arch`, and place the kernel and intramfs there.  And then change the configuration accordingly.  First `\loader\entries\arch.conf`:

```
title    Arch Linux
linux    \arch\vmlinuz-linux
initrd   \arch\initramfs-linux.img
options  root=PARTUUID=14420948-2cea-4de7-b042-40f67c618660 rw
```

The `/etc/fstab` configuration becomes more complicated in this case, you need to mount the UEFI partition somewhere else (not `/boot`) and then bind it to `/boot`.  For example using `/efi` as an intermediate mount point:

```
<UEFI part> /efi vfat defaults 0 0
/efi/EFI/arch /boot none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I will at some point this weekend!  Thanks for all of the detail you put into this!